# Issue with 'ViewPropTypes.styles' after upgrading expo from 45 to 46 and 'fixing' deprecated-props

Tags: react-native, expo, deprecated, react-proptypes

I have just upgraded expo from 45 to 46 to run on my physical device (apparently this update is need for the expo app). Both of this issues came up:

[image]
[image]

I have found many solutions for the deprecated module, most of them with this fix: upgrading on `node_moldules/react-native/index.tsx` (as many solutions suggest):

```
},
  // Deprecated Prop Types
  get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ColorPropType;
  },
  get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').EdgeInsetsPropType;
  },
  get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').PointPropType;
  },
  get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
    require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes;
  },
};
```

Although after doing this "solution", I got the following error (and the "main" error persists too):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I manage to solve it.

What has to be done?

1. Install `patch-package` and `deprecated-react-native-prop-types`.

2. In `node_moldules/react-native/index.tsx`. Insert the `require` lines:

```
 // Deprecated Prop Types
  get ColorPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ColorPropType;
  },
  get EdgeInsetsPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').EdgeInsetsPropType;
  },
  get PointPropType(): $FlowFixMe {
    require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').PointPropType;
  },
  get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
    require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes;
  },
};
```

3. Probably you will get the same issue with props as me, this means that some of your dependencies are outdated. Search for `PropTypes.style` (On every dependency on `node_modules` -> "yes it is boring and exhaustive", what I did to find the dependencies with issue was to comment all my code, and slowly uncomment it, so when the error shows I know which page is causing it), after finding the dependency with `PropTypes.style`, try to update the dependencies with `yarn <dependencie>`. If it does not fix the issue, then replace `PropTypes.style` with `require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types').ViewPropTypes`.

4. If updating dependencies fixed for you, your done.

5. If you had to include `require(...)` in any of the dependencies, don't forget to run `yarn patch-package <package-name>`

6. And also don't forget to run `yarn patch-package` after installing any packages with `yarn` or `npm`